# How can i control download process in linux

Tags: java, linux, groovy, wget

I have to download a file to remote file via ssh using java/groovy like this

```
process = "ssh 113.114.115.116 sudo wget http://webserver.com/file.zip".execute()
```

how can i control or known when file is complete downloaded or error occurrence and response to process ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab( 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.9.2' )
@Grab( 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.50' )

def doExec( host, uid, pwd, cmd ) {
    new AntBuilder().with {
        // Turn off logging
        project.buildListeners.firstElement().messageOutputLevel = 0

        // Execute command
        sshexec( host           : host,
                 username       : uid, 
                 password       : pwd,
                 command        : cmd,
                 outputproperty : 'result' )

        // Return output         
        project.properties.result
    }
}

println doExec( '113.114.115.116',
                'USERNAME',
                'PASSWORD',
                'sudo wget http://webserver.com/file.zip' )
```